# C++ Execute Commandline and get Result

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to use the Command Line (CMD.exe) to execute a function (like "DIR" ; CD ect.) and read Out the result. I Tryd it with POPEN but the Problem is, that i can only execute 1 order.
Something like

```
cd .. 
dir
```

wouldnt work in the way, that i do it.

Here is my "fake code", how i want to do that

```
Get Order from USER
Execute in Commandline
Print out the Result
Jump to start
```

I did it like that.
The Objekt "S" is part of my socket class.

```
while (1)
{
    //GET THE ORDER
    std::string r = s->ReceiveLine();

    if (r.empty()) break;
    cout<<r<<endl;
    //EXECUTE THE ORDER
    FILE *fp = popen(r.c_str(),"r");

    char buf[2560];
    //READ THE RESULT AND SEND TO USER
    while (fgets(buf, 2560, fp))
    {
        s->SendBytes(buf);
    }

    s->SendLine("123++END");


}
```

Hope youre able to understand my problem, my english isnt that good :$

Thanks!

Comment: Then put everything in a .cmd or .bat file, and execute that.

Comment: wont work for my programm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that when you use popen, you're creating a new process and then a pipe to that process. When you run a command line "cd ..", you're only changing the working directory of that process. You can use popen as many times as you want but make sure to use pclose when you're done with it.

For example, this would be a basic shell:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        cout << "% ";
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        if (line == "exit")
            break;
        auto fp = popen(line.c_str(), "r");
        string out;
        for (;;) {
            char buf[512];
            auto n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
            if (!n)
                break;
            out.append(buf, n);
        }
        pclose(fp);
        cout << out;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that dosent help to execute another function,

Comment: For example to change the dir and then get the dir

Comment: That cannot be done reliably for reasons outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905574/how-to-get-the-environment-variables-of-a-subprocess-after-it-finishes-running