# How to read variable exported from shell script , in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have two script
1. demo.ksh
2. demo.py

in demo.ksh i am exporting variable as

```
#!/bin/ksh
TEST="Hello"
export TEST
```

in demo.py I am executing demo.ksh and trying to read exported value as ..

```
import os
import subprocess
cmd='. demo.ksh' #I even tried 'demo.py' (no .)
subprocess(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(os.getenv('TEST'))
print(os.environ['TEST'])
```

I am expecting

```
Hello
Hello
```

But getting

```
None
KeyError: 'TEST'
```

Although it is a simple exercise. I could not find correct solution for this.Please help me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Why can't you use script stdout? With environment variables it would be difficult because it slightly hard to get another process environment variables. You can read about it more there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905574/how-to-get-the-environment-variables-of-a-subprocess-after-it-finishes-running

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a variable makes it available to *sub-processes* of the spawned shell process, but not to the parent process (i.e. your Python program).

To get the expected output try a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

TEST="Hello"
export TEST
python demo.py
```

You can instead communicate with the subprocess via STDOUT. For this, [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) can be useful.